# How do i write a binary tree generated to a 'txt file' (or an ascii file) in adjacency matrix format?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, data-visualization

I have a header file that when used outputs a binary tree by printing it on screen using `std::cout`. The tree data structure is  currently implemented as  `vector<Node>`
How can I use this`vector<Node>` to transform the content and write it as  an adjacency matrix to an ascii text file?
each node is

````
struct Node {
    int p;
    vector<int> c;
    float d;

```                                                                                                                                              and  tree is vector<Node>. I have implemented the tree in vector representation rather than pointer. Right now its a binary tree with each parent i having children at 2*i and 2*i+1                                                                                                                                               The expected output format as an example is 
EXAMPLE  :
     <br>A
     <br>@ B
     <br>@ @ C
    
Defines a simple complete graph with 3 nodes (with labels A B C) and no label (or value) on its edges```
Can someone point me towards resources that will help me learn these concepts?
thank you
````

Comment: I guess you mean `struct nodes { ... }`; `struct<nodes>` makes no sense in C++ (`struct` is a keyword and doesn’t get template arguments). The first step is to make the nodes identifiable. So you should add (e.g.) a unique integer initialized from a counter. The next step is to traverse the tree, e.g. in DFS order (BFS works too but DFS is easier to quickly prototype unless your tree is deeper than stack limits allow). In (e.g.) a `std::map<size_t, std::set<size_t>>` you record each node’s descendants. Finally, you iterate through the map and nested sets to generate matrix lines and columns.

Comment: sorry my bad, that was some brainfade moment from my end :) its actually vector<Node>, have updated the question                                                                                      Do you have any resources that would help me udnerstand this, i am at a very beginner level, so i am finding it difficult to grasp the concept

Comment: Can you show what your binary tree structure looks like and what you expect the file to look like?

Comment: Maybe Wikipedia helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

Comment: Hi i have updated the question with more details thanks

Comment: The [`std::vector` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) will be a good place to start. I bet the `Node` is a `struct` or `class` that (recursively) contains a further `std::vector<Node>` to form a tree-like structure (although I would guess it is a `std::vector<Node*>`, maybe, because with pointers the tree will be easier to rebalance / restructure if needed). But anyway, it looks like an exercise in basic concepts like BFS, DFS and C++ + STL fundamentals.